# PHP CURL - Empty output with no error

Tags: php, curl

I am not getting the curl output for valid url,
sample $url= http://linkedin.com/pub/4/b29/8a0

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,       60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$referer = WebCrawl::getRandomURL();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,       $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,     "cookie.txt");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

$body = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
```

Comment: Are you actually outputting `$error_no` at some point?

Comment: it was added to check any error

Comment: Yes, but are you actually *outputting* the result somewhere? With the code above, you will not see errors

Comment: i got the output from getURL method. thanks heart_hacker and pekka

Comment: I wasted lot of time. on my part this settings ssl verifier is the fix curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getURL($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($tmp != false){
            return $tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had similar issue. thanks, your code works well. but can you explain what is the wrong in the code given in question? and how come your code works well?

Comment: You should explain the reason

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` is redirecting you after the curl. Most like you forgot a trailing '/' in your URL.